# Parsing Email Address to fetch domain and comparing it

Tags: java, javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have a requirement where in a request containing  field comes in to my rest webservice.

In my webservice, I have to check for this  field and if the validation for this passes, then I send the request to a third party service.

**Validation Required:**

`message_from` field contains an `email address` as `string`. I have to check if the `domain name`(everything after `@`) is `roin.com`

For ex: `abc@roin.com` passes, `john_mandoza@roin.com` passes, `john_manodza@google.com` fails...

Can I use pattern matchers or anything else to do this validation?

I have used string parsing to capture everything after `(@)` and then did an `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare it with `roin.com`

This string parsing approach works, but is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why to use regex? Take the 9 last character of the string and check if they are `@roin.com`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this pattern `(\\S+?@roin\\.com)`: -

- `\\S+` is used to match any non-space character
- `?` after `\\S+` is used to do reluctant matching. It will match least number of character to satisfy the pattern
- `\\.` is used to match `.`
- Since `.` is a special character in Regex, that is why we need to escape it to match it as literal.

So, here's the code: -

```
String str = "abc@roin.com";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+?@roin\\.com");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Matches"); // Prints this for this email
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer rohit...Can you tell me what is "\\S+" and "\\" doing in the pattern?

Comment: @user1717230 `\\S+` is used to match any non-space character before your `@`. and `\\.` is used to escape the `dot`. `.` has a special meaning in Regex. So, you need to escape that..